# screenshot part of web using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

is it possible to capture a specific part of a web ui (like using the image's coordintes? Not the whole page!) using selenium web driver? I'm using java to write my script.  Thanks

Comment: Not out of the box. Instead, take a screenshot of the entire page, get the desired element's bounds and coordinates and crop the image accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @qqilihq

Comment: @jainishkapadia I believe the link you shared is taking the whole web page.  My concern is taking multiple screenshots which is part or within (may it be in random location) of a web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to share how I've resolved this issue using Multiscreenshot jar. Thanks.

```
import multiScreenShot.MultiScreenShot; 

WebElement object1 = driver.findElement(By.Id("MyObject"));
object1.click();
MultiScreenShot multiScreens = new MultiScreenShot("C:\\", "test"); // Path where you save the image
multiScreens.elementScreenShot(driver, object1);
WebElement object2 = driver.findElement(By.Id("YourObject"));
object2.click();
multiScreens.elementScreenShot(driver, object2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this part of code will help you.

```html
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));

// Get entire page screenshot
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

// Get the location of element on the page
Point point = ele.getLocation();

// Get width and height of the element
int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();

// Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(),
    eleWidth, eleHeight);
ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);

// Copy the element screenshot to disk
File screenshotLocation = new File("C:\\images\\GoogleLogo_screenshot.png");
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);
```

Comment: This looks good to me.  I feel that this will work on my project.  Thanks @Lucky for the help.